# After updating to Android Studio Chipmunk, the iOS Simulator no longer shows

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-studio-chipmunk

I am no longer able to run the iOS simulator in Android Studio after updating from Android Studio Bumblebee(2021.1.1) to Android Studio Chipmunk(2021.2.1), and I have tried everything I can think of.

- I also tried clearing the cache and restarting Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated AndroidStudio but that is not problem

• I Also updated flutter from 2.10.2 to 3.0.1 and latest flutter version(3.0.1) is not support my xcode version(12.3) it requires bigger xcode version than mine one.

-> Solution :- Downgrade flutter or upgrade xcode

-> suggestion:- you can use fvm(Flutter Version management) for use different flutter version for different project

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in Windows.
Finally I deleted Android Studio and android sdk. Then I installed the new version of Android Studio and installed the sdk according to the Android Studio wizard and the problem was solved.

**UPDATE**:
Main problem on android sdk and emulator part .don't use old android sdk (delete/reinstall android sdk). by default if not installed android sdk , android studio at first launch recommend install steps.

Comment: Still having problems After you've uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio,

Comment: The iOS simulator is also not visible in VSCode; I am confident that this is not a problem with Android Studio.

Comment: main problem on android sdk and emulator part .don't use old android sdk (delete/reinstall android sdk). by default if not installed android  sdk , android studio at first launch recommend install steps.